# Javascript hide content in label tag and label tag after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide text based on the text in a label tag and I want to hide text in the next label tag to. I know how to make it hide the username cause that text will always be the same, but I don't know how to make it hide the users message.

Here's what the code looks like:

```html
<div id="chatbox">
 <label id="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
 <label id="cnick">BlockMe:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
 <label id="cnick">BlockMe:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
 <label id="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
 <label id="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
</div>
```

This is what i want it to look like after the javascript runs:

```html
<div id="chatbox">
 <label id="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
 <label id="cnick" style="display: none">BlockMe:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg" style="display: none">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
 <label id="cnick" style="display: none">BlockMe:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg" style="display: none">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
 <label id="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
 <label id="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
 <br>
 <label id="cmsg">Some random text</label>
 <div id="cspc"></div>
 <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the JavaScipt that you've got already.

Comment: You could create a <div> container for each username/message. It will be easier to hide it.

Comment: Notice that <br> is a quite bad pratice. You should add a CSS margin-bottom to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using jquery, you could use .html() to get the value inside the element, and then use .next() to grab the next label element.

Something like:

```
$('label').each(function(){
 if($(this).html() == "BlockMe:"){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().hide()
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First : Please notice that an ID has to be unique.
'cnick', 'cmsg', 'cspc' should be classes.

You could create a  container for each username/message. It will be easier to hide it.

```
<div id="chatbox">
    <div class="msg-box">
        <label class="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
        <br>
        <label class="cmsg">Some random text</label>
        <div class="cspc"></div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="msg-box">
        <label class="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
        <br>
        <label class="cmsg">Some random text</label>
        <div class="cspc"></div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="msg-box">
        <label class="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
        <br>
        <label class="cmsg">Some random text</label>
        <div class="cspc"></div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="msg-box">
        <label class="cnick">OtherUsers:</label>
        <br>
        <label class="cmsg">Some random text</label>
        <div class="cspc"></div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you have to be able to find with jquery wich boxes you wan't to hide with a selector (a class, id or anything else) and you can hide the boxes like this :

```
$(mySelector).hide();
```